# How do I list the hot links of a subreddit via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

What's a good way to retrieve subreddit links via API in PowerShell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reddit serves content by JSON if you put `.json` on the end of a URI, and PowerShell can use that. Hot links on /r/programming :

```
(irm https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/hot/.json).data.children.data | select score, subreddit, title, url
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach which doesn't depend on any third party libraries. I.e. it's in terms of pure PowerShell.

Let's assume you're keeping your reddit credentials, reddit app client ID and reddit app client secret in files:

```
$username          = Get-Content $env:APPDATA\reddit-username
$password          = Get-Content $env:APPDATA\reddit-password

$app_client_id     = Get-Content $env:APPDATA\reddit-app-client-id
$app_client_secret = Get-Content $env:APPDATA\reddit-app-client-secret
```

(See [this page](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2) for information about getting a reddit client ID.)

Retrieve an access token:

```
$result_access_token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token' `
    -Method Post `
    -Headers @{ 
        Authorization = ('Basic {0}' -f (
            [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(
                "${app_client_id}:${app_client_secret}"))))
    } `
    -Body @{ 
        grant_type = 'password'
        username   = $username
        password   = $password
    }
```

Let's extract the token from the result and assign it to a variable:

```
$token = $result_access_token.access_token
```

Now let's get the current *hot* links on `/r/programming`:

```
$result_listing = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://oauth.reddit.com/r/programming/hot' -Headers @{ Authorization = "bearer $token" }
```

Show the links:

```
$result_listing.data.children | ForEach-Object data | Select-Object score, subreddit, title, url
```

Example output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Example using [PSRAW](https://github.com/markekraus/PSRAW)

1. Log into Reddit
2. Log into Reddit
3. Navigate to https://ssl.reddit.com/prefs/apps
4. Click the create app or create another app button
5. Enter a name (e.g. "(Reddit Username)'s PSRAW App")
6. Choose the Script radio button
7. Enter a description (e.g. "My first PSRAW App!")
8. In the about url box enter `https://127.0.0.1`
9. In the redirect URI box enter `https://127.0.0.1`
10. Click the create app button

Then define your Reddit application, get a token, and export it:

```
Install-Module -Name PSRAW -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module PSRAW

$ClientCredential = Get-Credential
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$RedirectUri = 'https://127.0.0.1'
$AppExportPath = 'C:\PSRAW\MyApp.xml'
$UserAgent = 'windows:markekraus-PSRAW:v0.0.0.1 (by /u/markekraus)'

$Scopes = 'read'
$Params = @{
    Script           = $True
    Name             = "markekraus's PSRAW App"
    Description      = 'My first PSRAW App!'
    ClientCredential = $ClientCredential
    UserCredential   = $UserCredential
    RedirectUri      = $RedirectUri
    UserAgent        = $UserAgent 
    Scope            = $Scopes
}
$RedditApp = New-RedditApplication @Params
$RedditApp | Export-RedditApplication -Path $AppExportPath

$TokenExportPath = 'C:\PSRAW\MyToken.xml'

$Token = $RedditApp | Request-RedditOAuthToken -Script
$Token | Export-RedditOAuthToken -Path $TokenExportPath
```

Now you can use `Invoke-RedditRequest` to make authenticated API calls:

```
$Uri = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/r/programming/hot'
$result_listing = $Token | Invoke-RedditRequest -Uri $Uri
$result_listing.ContentObject.data.children.data | 
    Select-Object score, subreddit, title, url
```

After first creating the application, getting a token, and exporting the token, something like this can be added to your profile to display when your session loads:

```
$TokenExportPath = 'C:\PSRAW\MyToken.xml'
$Uri = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/r/programming/hot'

$Token = Import-RedditOAuthToken -Path $TokenExportPath
$result_listing = $Token | Invoke-RedditRequest -Uri $Uri
$result_listing.ContentObject.data.children.data | 
    Select-Object score, subreddit, title, url
```